# How to export my eclipse java project to the remote server as a runnable jar?

Tags: eclipse, ant, jar

Is there a way to export my eclipse java project as a runnable jar to my remote server directly from eclipse. Can this be done using Ant?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes this can be done by ant. Use the [jar](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/jar.html) task to create a jar and the [scp](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/scp.html) task to transfer your jar to a server.

Some examples:

```
<target name="jar" depends="compile">
    <mkdir dir="${dist}" />
    <jar jarfile="${dist}/myjar.jar" basedir="${target}">
        <fileset dir="${source}">
            <include name="**/*.gif" />
            <include name="**/*.properties" />
        </fileset>
    </jar>
</target>

<target name="dist" depends="jar" >
    <scp file="${dist}/myjar.jar" trust="true" keyfile="/tmp/keyfile.openssh" todir="user@server:/directory" passphrase="phrase" />
</target>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could add a network driver mapping, then export it to remote server like local.